# generation spaceship with kids and rats

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship

I am looking for a book for my son to read that I read when I was about his age. I cannot remember the name of it but I think it was a trilogy (or at least a book in three acts). I read it in the late 70's. My most vivid memory is that the last part of the book was about some kids that were all that remained of a generation ship that had been launched many years before at a distant star. There was still one creepy old man who couldn't leave the hub of the ship because the gravity would kill him. There were packs of rats that the kids had to avoid. In the closing chapter, the kids are deposited on their new world and look back to see the old ship passing overhead on its way to plunge into the sun.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 11):

I think that's probably the [Exiles Trilogy](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/302478.The_Exiles_Trilogy) by Ben Bova -- but it's been decades since I read them.

Edited to add: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is. [This review](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/206534600) (which contains spoilers) fits in pretty well with your description.

Comment: This is a strong candidate, the rats and the old man appear in the second book, I believe, as the first concerns the plight of the original crew on arriving at their planned destination to find it less suitable than expected.

Comment: Yes!  That sounds right!

Comment: You should put some of the matching details directly into your answer.